# How can I enable common Latex shortcuts for em-dashes (---) and quotation marks (`` '') while using a system font?

Tags: fonts, punctuation, macos, texpad

I am using TexpadTeX (from the Mac application Texifier/TexPad) and am trying to use Adobe's Garamond Premier Pro font, which is a system font on MacOS.

I'm also very used to using some widely-used TeX/LaTeX commands for dashes and quotation marks, namely `` and '' for double quotation marks and `---` for em-dashes. However, these appear to be disabled when I use `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
 BoldFont={Garamond Premier Pro Bold}, 
 ItalicFont={Garamond Premier Pro Italic},
 BoldItalicFont={Garamond Premier Pro Bold Italic}
 ]{Garamond Premier Pro}

\begin{document}
“Quotation”

``Quotation''

Em dash ---

Em dash —
\end{document}
```

produces the following:

[image: Quotation and dash differences]

Ideally, I would like the two pairs of lines to be identical. From reading other questions here, I know that this has something to do with ligatures, and that I could probably disable all Garamond Premier Pro ligatures, but I would like to keep those (especially the long Q and the ff, fi, etc. ligatures).

Is there a command I can use to replace --- with an em dash and `` and '' with double quotation marks in typesetting?

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Have you tried adding `Ligatures=TeX` into your `\setmainfont` options?

Comment: @gz839918 I tried this but I wasn’t able to find where to insert the command. Putting it before or after  “\setmainfont[
 BoldFont={Garamond Premier Pro Bold}, 
 ItalicFont={Garamond Premier Pro Italic},
 BoldItalicFont={Garamond Premier Pro Bold Italic}
 ]{Garamond Premier Pro}” gave me an error, but I could be trying to place it wrong.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you've encountered on a MacOS 13.5.1 Ventura/MacTeX2023 system. Please tell us more about TeXPad -- and how it differs from MacTeX2023.

Comment: What happens if you change `\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}` to `\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]`? The option `Ligatures={Common,TeX}` is usually enabled by default when `\setmainfont` is executed.

Comment: What happens if you run `\setmainfont{GaramondPremrPro}[Extension = .otf, ItalicFont = *-It, BoldFont = *-Smbd, BoldItalicFont = *-SmbdIt, Ligatures = {Common,TeX}]`?

Comment: @Mico Thank you so much for your help! I tried both of these and got several errors for both. Here is a full log: [attempt at first proposed solution](https://pastebin.com/QhNdk3fu) [attempt at second proposed solution](https://pastebin.com/0fSPJUka)

Comment: Is there any chance at all for you to make use of a more recent set of vintages of  the packages that are used by TexPadTeX? The reason I ask is that according to the log files you provided links to, your system is using a vintage-2017 version of the `fontspec` package, whereas the current one is dated `2022/01/15`.